# magento 2 custom theme css not working on frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, css, js-css

I'm using to make a custom theme and applied to it. after installing any modules than front-end CSS not working.
Some time replace the .htaccess file from official link than working.
anyone can fix it.

How to resolve this issue.

I'm also run these commands many times but not fix.

```
sudo php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following step to create your own theme:

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/theme.xml
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/registration.php
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/composer.json
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/media
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/media/m2-theme-image.jpg
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/css
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/css/source
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/css/fonts
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/css/images
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/web/css/js
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/etc
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/etc/view.xml
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout
>       /app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

After that set your theme from admin panel and run command.

Comment: You don't need a lot of those files to create a theme.

Comment: @BenCrook,guide to exactly what to do.Already configure above step.but after upgrade modules then this type of problem occurs.